# ActionBarSherlock support v4?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying use ActionBarSherlock in my project. I deleted `android-support-v4` of my project and add `actionbarsherlock` like a library, but when I try use android-support-v4 for example to create DrawerLayout or a ActionBarDrawerToggle doesn't works because no found android-support-v4 and doesn't import package.

How can I solve it ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: don't remove support-v4? It contains more than just actionbar support

Comment: @zapl I can not remove support-v4 of my project did you say ?

Comment: ActionbarSherlock does not include DrawerLayout but v4 does. Add it back to you project and the problem will be solved. I also wouldn't recommend to use ActionbarSherlock. It's not updated anymore since Google released it's v7 appcompat library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a better way to add this library: Go to your project properties->android, in the "Library" zone click "add" and select the actionbarsherlock project.

Good look